# remove string from variable based on matched rows

Tags: t-sql

I have a small problem and I know a few solutions for it, but I don't know the best way (or less dirty spaghetti way) to go.

I have a string variable, and I need to use it in a like expression.

So:

```
declare @a varchar(100) = 'my string to use as a join from'

select *
from table
where
    column like '%' + @a + '%'
```

But I don't want any rows from table that contains the @a variable, I want any rows from table that are contained in the @a variable, so:

```
select *
from table
where
    @a like '%' + column + '%'
```

Result:

```
'my string'
'as a join from'
```

But now I need to remove the matched rows from the @a variable. How can I do that?

(edit)

expected result:

```
@a = ' to use '

'my string'
'as a join from'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can alter the value of `@a` with each matched row in the select:

```
select @a = replace(@a, MyColumn, '')
  from MyTable
 where @a like '%' + MyColumn + '%'
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/187d6/5 (result: `@a = ' to use '`)

---

If you want to get a result set as well, use a temp table to store matching rows:

```
select MyColumn
  into #Temp
  from MyTable
 where @a like '%' + MyColumn + '%'

-- @a = ' to use '
select @a = replace(@a, MyColumn, '') from #Temp

-- returns result set of words that matched
select * from #Temp

drop table #Temp
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/187d6/13

Comment: what about the problem relative to the fact that I can't assign a value and retrieve data in the same statement? I need those words!

Comment: You can do two queries, the first where you generate the result set, and the second where you update `@a`.

Comment: yes, it's expensive, but you are right. is there another clever way like this one that I'm ignoring? (maybe a less expensive one)

Comment: Yes, the first query gets you the matching rows.  You only need to find the matching rows once, so you could put those in a temp table for instance.  See updated example.